# GWT Super Dev does not work in IE 11

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-11

After compiler my application in GWT Super Dev Mode,

Run: "http://localhost:9876/" in IE 11,
see the followings,

GWT Code Server

1.Drag these two bookmarklets to your browser's bookmark bar: 
Dev Mode On Dev Mode Off

................
3.Click "Dev Mode On" to start development mode.

when click "Dev Mode On",  is shows "Can't find any GWT Modules on this page."

Anyone knows how to debug GWT in IE 11?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of GWT are you using ?

Comment: I'd like to remove the internet-explorer-11 tag, as the issue OP experienced was actually not browser specific, but an issue of proper procedure.

I ended up here looking for IE specific answers, and this was not helpful to me, though it will be to others who are new to super dev mode.

Answer (score 2):

Phase 1

1. Compile your project
2. Host it in some webserver
3. Test it by surfing to this URL

Now phase 2

1. Run as superdevmode
2. The SuperDevMode page opens
3. Surf to the website you created in phase 1
4. Click the DevMode on bookmarklet you placed in your bookmarks bar
5. The app should compile

Answer (score 0):

You are missing point 2 (which you left out here):

> Visit a web page that uses one of these modules: [your_module_name]

So probably you didn't define a startup url for your run configuration (which IDE are you using?). You can do this with the argument `-startupUrl index.html`. The `index.html` should be placed in your output war directory.

Depeding on the port you configured (default 8888) you have to visit this html-page (with the `module.js` injected of course) to start the compilation. An example url would be:

127.0.0.1:8888/index.html

To debug your application in IE 11 you have to set breakpoints with `GWT.debugger()` for the client code. For the server code you can use the breakpoints of your IDE. To use the clientside-breakpoints you have to open the Developer Tools of your browser (F12 in case of IE11). There go to debugger/sources or however the tab is called in the case of your browser and debug your application client code directly in the browser. Keep in mind to use source maps to map your Java source code to the generated JS file.